# React Material UI manually trigger Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to duplicate Material UI's language changer https://material-ui.com/.

So as you can see, I wrapped an icon + Mui Select into a Mui Button.
By the way, if you have an idea for a better implementation you're welcome!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Select, MenuItem, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import TranslateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Translate';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    '&:before': {
      borderColor: 'white',
    },
    '&:after': {
      borderColor: 'white',
    },
    color: 'white',
  },
}));

const LanguageChanger = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { i18n, t } = useTranslation();
  const listLanguage = React.createRef();

  const langSwitch = [
    { code: 'en-US', title: t('Language.English') },
    { code: 'fr', title: t('Language.French') },
  ];

  const handleChange = event => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  const renderSelect = language => {
    return (
      <Button
        color='inherit'
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(listLanguage);
          listLanguage.current.click();
        }}
      >
        <TranslateIcon />
        <Select
          className={classes.root}
          id='select-language'
          ref={listLanguage}
          value={language}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {langSwitch.map((lang, index) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={lang.code}>
                {lang.title}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </Button>
    );
  };

  return renderSelect(i18n.language);
};

export default LanguageChanger;
```

My problem here is to open MuiSelect with a click on his parent's Mui Button. No errors, the Mui Select is just taking the focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it like this [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/b40px) using a state to handle the Select open flag, not the best solution in my opinion by it works.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Select, MenuItem, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import TranslateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Translate";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    "&:before": {
      borderColor: "white"
    },
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: "white"
    },
    color: "white"
  }
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { i18n, t } = useTranslation();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const langSwitch = [
    { code: "en-US", title: t("Language.English") },
    { code: "fr", title: t("Language.French") }
  ];

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  const renderSelect = (language) => {
    return (
      <Button
        color="inherit"
        onClick={() => {
          setOpen(!open);
        }}
      >
        <TranslateIcon />
        <Select
          className={classes.root}
          id="select-language"
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          value={language}
          onChange={handleChange}
          open={open}
        >
          {langSwitch.map((lang, index) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={lang.code}>
                {lang.title}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </Button>
    );
  };

  return renderSelect(i18n.language);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: This works! Thank you, I didn't think about that open props.

Comment: Could you add some code snippets from your solution please? Sometimes URLs can get broken, at least some part of the answer will stay here for others to find. Thanks

Comment: Sure, unfortunally I cannot update the answer and the code is too many chars to be pasted, do you have a suggestion how I can solve this?

Comment: You should be able to update your answer with code from `App.js` file with no problem. I will try that for you